# How to export a flextable table from r as a good quality interactive table

Tags: r, image, export, flextable, image-quality

I have this dataframe

```
df = data.frame(x = 1:20, y = 2:21, z = 3:22)
```

and when applying `flextable` and exporting the image I have this result :

```
flextable(df)
```

[image]

I don't know how to export it as a complete table, interactive and in a good quality.

would appreciate the help.

Comment: https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/save_as_image.html ?

Comment: there is a bug and it seems to produce bad quality photo and not interactive